# How to check if a string contains a word when applying association_rules?

Tags: python, string, pandas, data-mining, apriori

I am applying association rules and selecting only rules with the following parameters, however I want to choose only the rules that do not have these itemsets"AL", "DIAB" no matter what their values are "0" "1", "y" or "n". How can I say: when the consequent contains "AL", "DIAB", do not select the rule. This is my code, but it is only precise on the exact string, not a substring

```
Selected_rules = rules[ (rules['antecedent_len'] <= 3) &
           (rules['confidence'] > 0.6) &
           (rules['lift'] > 1) & ( rules['consequents'] != {'AL = 1'} ) & (rules['consequents'] != {'DIAB = n'})  ]
```

For example, I do not want this rule to be selected as it has both "AL", and "DIAB"

```
frozenset(['SEX = F', 'Age = 70'])              frozenset(['AL = 0', 'DIAB = y'])                    0.25                 0.25                 0.25      1         4            0.1875         inf                   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing with equality, why don't you just use the `in` operator?

```
'AL = 1' in rule['consequents']
```

Of course it would make more sense to only generate the rules of interest in the first place rather than filtering them afterwards, and work with a more efficient data structure than with sets of strings...